# If Statement With Contains And Downcase In Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm attempting to use `downcase` inside of an `if` statement, while using the `contains` criteria. I can't believe there isn't a Google-able solution.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
{% if collection.tags | downcase contains "womens" %}
{% if {{collection.tags | downcase}} contains "womens" %}
{% if {{collection.tags}} | downcase contains "womens" %}
```

I'd like to not have to loop the array and assign the downcased strings back into a new array if possible, just to keep things clean and efficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't manipulate values inside of an `if` statement in Liquid - you'll need to assign the downcased values to a variable, then use that.

So in your case, something like:

```
{% assign collection_tags = collection.tags | join: '~~~' | downcase | split: '~~~' %}
{% if collection_tags contains 'womens' %}
```

---

#### Note:

`downcase` is a string operation, not an array operation, so the above code uses `join` to turn the array into a single long string with some delimiter that shouldn't appear in any of your tags, then `split`-ing that string back into an array using the same delimiter after changing the case.

If we just use `downcase` on the array itself, Shopify will implicitly join the array using an empty string, and your `contains` statement would then be looking for the substring `womens` in the resulting blob. For contrast, when using `contains` on an array, Shopify will only match a tag that is an exact-match of your search term.

To illustrate, if your collection tags are `['Not-For-Women','Stuff']`, `downcase`-ing the array directly will give you the string `'not-for-womenstuff'`, which happens to contain the substring 'womens' and would be an unexpected false-positive.

Comment: As an addendum, Liquid braces are never nested - `{% if x == {{ variable }} %}` is never used, the correct syntax is always `{% if x == variable %}` :)

Comment: This worked perfectly, and the explanations were helpful. Thanks @Dave B

Comment: @DaveB Thank you for your answer it worked for me!!!

I was wonderign, im new to Liquid and trying to figure out some syntax. can the assign be put into If somehtign like this`{% if collection.tags | join: '~~~' | downcase | split: '~~~' contains 'womens' %}`

Comment: @knowzero: No, the `if` statements need to be simple comparisons in Liquid. You would need to `assign` a variable to the tag array before the `if` statement and then use that. :)